# Подсчет средного значение чисел вводящихся в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть `textbox1` и `textbox2`. В `textbox1` вводятся 4 разные цифры по очереди, каждый раз одну цифру. В коде должно подсчитываться среднее значение суммы этих цифр и выводиться в `textbox2`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    if (!(textBox17.Text == null))
    {
        list.Add(int.Parse(textBox17.Text));
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += list[i];
        }
        textBox17.Clear();
    }
    textBox18.Text = (sum / 4).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Код пробовали писать? Покажите.

Comment: вот но это работает только с одним значением и все?   '  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            if (!(textBox17.Text == null))
            {
                
                list.Add(int.Parse(textBox17.Text));
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    sum += list[i];
                }
                textBox17.Clear();       
            }
            textBox18.Text = (sum / 4).ToString();
        }'

Comment: сильное подозрение, что подразумеваются не "цифры", а "числа"

Comment: @VardanVardanyan - сделайте `List<int> list = new List<int>();` не локальной переменной, а членом класса формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список введенных чисел должен быть общим во всех нажатиях на кнопку, так что стоит сделать его полем класса - просто переставить повыше, вне обработчика:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;

    // if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(textBox17.Text)) - пустая строка и null - разные вещи
    if (!(textBox17.Text == null))
    {
        list.Add(int.Parse(textBox17.Text));

        // можно заменить на sum = list.Sum();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            sum += list[i];
        }
        textBox17.Clear(); // = "";
    }

    // стоит делить на 4.0 вместо 4 - чтобы получить дробный результат
    textBox18.Text = (sum / 4).ToString(); 
}
```

и еще - стоит переименовать текстбоксы. textBox17 и textBox18 не добавляют читабельности.

Answer (score 0):

```
            float sum = 0;
            int count = 0;

            foreach (char digit in textBox1.Text)
            {
                if (char.IsNumber(digit)
                {
                    sum += byte.Parse(digit.ToString());
                    count++;
                }
            }

            textBox2.Text = (sum / count).ToString();
```

Comment: Есть метод [`Char.GetNumericValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx) для перевода символа в число